# How can I test my php webservice on performance?

Tags: php, performance, testing

I'm making a simple app for a customer who claimed to have a webservice for me to use for the app, but as it turns out, he doesn't.
Now I am a total noob in php and have never worked with it before, but I managed to follow through this great tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app

I made some modifications to the webservice, but the way I have it now, the webservice connects to the database in every single method (But I need only 1 method call per access, so it's not a big deal I guess).

I tried to have one global variable for my db link and use it in every method, but I failed. Searched the internetz and found that if I'd have a global variable for the connection, that I could only have one connection at the time and I'd need a pool to have more connections at once.

1. Is it true, that I can have only one connection (from the client to the webservice AND from the webservice to the databse) at the time the way I have it?
2. A pool? How do I implement a pool?
3. How can I test my webservice performance wise?

I can test one single access by this typing this in my mac terminal:

```
curl -F "ID=1" http://192.168.1.2/webservice.php
```

Is it possible to loop this?

Comment: That didn't answer anything

Comment: Why do you need multiple database connection? Its a bad idea to have a database connection for each user. Server can handle multiple requests simultaneously .. why you feel only one user can access your web service at a time? What is the problem u r facing??? Generally pool is required if you have high traffic.

Comment: So if my server is powerful enough, many users can access the webservice.php without having to program a queue?

Comment: Assuming you webservice is running in a web server environment, why not allow the webserver's queue do its job?